# Php SMTP Mail sending works only local

Tags: php, email, smtp, send

I'm trying since hours now to get a mailscript working on a live server. It works as intended on my localhost.

I'm using exact the same external SMTP server, the same PHP sources and the same databasetables too. The PHP version and MySQL version online and localhost are identical.

I tested everything. Everything works as pretended without the physical sending process. It doesn't send (or receive) email. I also went to the systemadministrator to let him check if there are any emails blocked or internal server errors, but here also everything fine.

I really tried everything I could think of but I didn't find the problem. Has anybody an idea what I could try next?

This is how the function for the physical sending looks like:

```
private function sendPhysical($sReciepient) {
    if ($oSmtpIn = fsockopen(SMTPSERVER, SMTPPORT)) {
        fputs($oSmtpIn, "EHLO " . SMTPSERVER . "\r\n");
        $aCodes["hello"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 1024);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, "auth login\r\n");
        $aCodes["res"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 1024);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, $this->encodeUser() . "\r\n");
        $aCodes["user"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 1024);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, $this->encodePassword() . "\r\n");
        $aCodes["pass"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 256);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, "MAIL FROM: <" . $this->sFrom . ">\r\n");
        $aCodes["From"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 1024);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, "RCPT TO: <" . $sReciepient . ">\r\n");
        $aCodes["To"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 1024);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, "DATA\r\n");
        $aCodes["data"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 1024);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, $this->generateHeader($sReciepient) . "\r\n\r\n" . $this->returnCompiledTemplate() . "\r\n.\r\n");
        $aCodes["send"] = fgets($oSmtpIn, 256);

        fputs($oSmtpIn, "QUIT\r\n");
        fclose($oSmtpIn);
    } else {
        $aCodes["connection"] = false;
    }
    return $aCodes;
}
```

Anybody a possible solution? I'm totally confused because it works at localhost and it already worked at the online server until last week...

Comment: Well, what is the actual error? What do you see/get? Most likely you will have to take a look at the network level. Probably you can spot some problem in the servers response. I bet it has to do with relaying. Could it be you are using your ISPs smtp server? If so: a relaying problem, the servers rules do not accept anyone from outside (your online server) to relay messages through it.

Comment: I dont see any actual error except that the mails are not send. No i'm using a smtp server of the firm i intern at (i'm still student).  The systemadministrator checked the logs but didnt find anything.. :/

Comment: nothing stops working all of sudden. If your code hasn't changed then it must be the rest of the network where change occurred. As already pointed out, Relays/MTAs?

Comment: but how can it happen that if i access the smtp from my local pc it works and if i upload it doesn't work anymore?  that seems illogical to me.. it is exact the same smtp server..

Comment: So what do you get inside those replies you read and store into variables in your code? You don't seem to evaluate those, so no wonder you don't see an error...

Comment: New incident:  Now it worked for 1 Email.. i didnt change anything and now i recieved 1 single Email. But if i repeat it i don't recieve another. Should it be a Serverproblem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite tricky too see what's wrong on with this block of code but if you don't want to have much trouble sending mail via php, try PHPMailer.